# A few questions about the definition of the BRDF

Tags: radiometry

Hi everyone (I'm sorry for my bad english)

I was reading the book "Physically-based rendering" and I came across the definition of the BRDF :
$ f(x,\theta, \psi) = dL(x\rightarrow\theta)/dE(x\leftarrow\psi) $

They say that the BRDF mesures how much light coming from the direction $\phi$ is reflected in the direction $\theta$. But why have they chosen this definition ? why not this one for example :

$ f(x,\theta, \psi) = dL_o(x\rightarrow\theta)/dL_i(x\leftarrow\psi) $

Furthermore, when they come to the reflection of a perfect mirror, they write :
$ L_o(x\rightarrow\theta) = F(\theta) L_i(x\leftarrow -\theta) $ where $F(\theta)$ stands for the Fresnel Coefficient. Why are we allowed to use the law of geometrical optics with radiance ? Does that mean that Radiance represents a bunch of rays ?

I'm very confused with this concept.
Thanks for your replies.

Comment: Comment to the question (v1): Consider to spell out acronym.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean with the different notations in the 2 first formulas. And I don't understand your last question as well (or is it "why and when can we rely on geometric optic in graphics?"). NB:  there exists http://computergraphics.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

The notation is weird and, IMHO, not very useful. It looks like one of those attempts of "originality" where the authors think, for whatever reason, that they have to introduce their own language to make old content look new. In theory the most complete "rendering algorithm" would be a Maxwell equation solver. In practice this fails because of the necessary numerical complexity. What it would get you is exactly what a real camera would see... which, as any cinematographer will tell you, is rarely a good thing, not even in cgi rendering. Since the direct approach at calculating the light field is doomed for all but the most trivial scenes, one has to develop a number of approximations. One common hierarchy of approximations will reduce the full problem to a scalar wave problem (to get rid of polarization), then apply an Eikonal approximation which eventually gets us down to the level of geometrical (ray) optics. These approximations can be made "from first principles", if you wish, and I happen to know someone who wrote a dissertation about this, but I don't think you will be able to locate it, I suspect that the only copies are in a dusty book shelf in a German university that shall remain unnamed. I am sure one could piece the derivation together from multiple easier to obtain sources.

Which approximation you want to chose for your "physical rendering problem" is up to you. The defense contractors who are building stealth aircraft are "rendering" their radar models using Maxwell's equations. Crystallographers are using plane wave approximations with either scalar or vector fields and don't care about more than the first scattering order. Electron microscopy and electron beam or deep UV lithography folks have to do a little better than that and will probably take a few higher orders into account. CGI rendering algorithms are typically using dynamics n-th order reflection cutoffs or are approximating the light field with a simplified implicit diffusion equation (there is a whole bunch of radiosity algorithms of that kind, if I remember correctly). Hollywood doesn't use any physical rendering theory. For them it's all about how the final result looks, physics be damned.

In this case Fresnel equations are the correct result for the reflection/transmission of a plane wave (and ONLY of a plane wave) on a single planar interface between otherwise infinite materials of constant refractive index. If your particular problem falls into that class, Fresnel is OK, if it doesn't... well, then you should not be using it.

Now, this is probably not what you were trying to ask, but the question "Why are we allowed..." leads invariable to the answer "We are "allowed" to use whatever works, no matter how wrong it may be in the most general case.".

Comment: "Hollywood doesn't use any physical rendering theory.": uh, you live 15 years in the past :-) . It's all about physical rendering, nowadays. Spectral transport, illuminants, camera response; complex BRDFs, phases function, deep multiple-scattering and sub-surface scattering, etc (but still with no wave optic or polarization, alas).

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: Hollywood rarely uses unchanged original footage these days. Most everything you see on the big screen is altered in profound ways. It starts with lighting and color corrections. The blur imposed by the camera lens is NOT the way a person would see the scene, it's a technological artifact that is used to isolate the action and to set the tone of a scene. Non-ideal location artifacts (e.g. electrical wires and buildings/vehicles of the wrong period) are removed or masked in post-processing. There is virtually NOTHING physical about movie making. It's an ART.

Comment: man, it's my professional world. So I know "a little bit". All the things you mention here occurs post-camera. CG has to mimic camera (otherwise integration would be craps), and will got same post-camera transforms.

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: If it's "your professional world", then you should actually know better. Even an amateur photographer and a movie buff with the slightest interest in the process of making movies can tell you that "physics" is the least of a movie makers concern. It's the emotional reaction of the audience that drives the process and there is not a single formula in physics that will help with that, especially not those for plane wave reflection on non-existing perfectly flat surfaces between two infinite media of constant index of refraction.

Comment: That just not the point. Tell directors to use bad optics in their cameras and you will see if they really don't care to have some physically correct things at some crucial stages, whatever is done with the pixels later. (And please, try to be a little bit less affirmative in your statements. What would you say about a non-physicist OP telling *you* that you should know physics better (that him) ?).

Comment: @FabriceNEYRET: The point is really simple, what you get by using Fresnel equations is this: https://walterhow.files.wordpress.com/2013/11/refraction_glass.jpg?w=460&h=258 (and technically even that is wrong as far as physics is concerned). Does that look like a good movie scene to you? How about this: http://faculty.frostburg.edu/phil/forum/moderntimes.jpg. Is this correct physics? Would you rather watch the glass ball or Charlie Chaplin?